# Quando colocar uma classe no DbSet usando Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first, migrations, dbset

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
```

sendo que elas têm uma relação one-to-many.

Quando eu quero que uma classe seja adicionada ao meu modelo de migração do EntityFramework, tenho de adiciona-la assim como tenho no código acima, por questões de mapeamento, acontece que eu criei mais uma classe `Category` e configurei uma relação many-to-many com a classe (tabela na base dados) `Request`, para a minha surpresa, a nova classe foi incluida na migração, sem eu a ter identificado como `DbSet`. A minha dúvida é a seguinte: se eu crio uma classe nova X e ela de alguma forma relaciona-se com uma classe Y no `DbSet` então a classe X é adicionada à base de dados automaticamente? No meu caso, poderia remover esta linha:

```
 public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
```

sem alterar o comportamento? (esta classe tem relação com a classe `Request`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comportamento de criação da classe na base de dados já é espero por conta do relacionamento, havendo uma relação com a classe **Category** ele irá entender que há um campo "FK" e para isso ocorrer precisa da tabela no banco de dados.

Quanto a precisar criar um `DbSet`, depende de como você usa o seu contexto.

Caso você não tenha um `DbSet` da classe **Category**, você não irá conseguir fazer o seguinte `seuContexto.Categories.Find(id);`, porém, há outra forma de "usar" esses métodos, `seuContexto.Set<SuaClasse>().Find(id);` note que dentro do operador diamantes(`<>`) é informado qual o tipo.

> No meu caso, poderia remover esta linha:

(opinião)Não aconselho que faça dessa forma, poderá ficar confuso e poderá se perder, ou usa tudo com `DbSet`, ou "usa" tudo com o `seuContexto.Set<SuaClasse>()`, mantenha o padrão.

Comment: Obrigado! Era isso mesmo

Answer (score 0):

O DbSet representa o "repository" da sua entidade é ele que possui os métodos Create, Find, Remove etc. Então, caso você não mapeie a entidade no dbset, não será possível fazer o Crud dela.

Se quiser, pode dar uma olhada no link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/dbset.aspx

Comment: mas a estrutura no SQL é criada na mesma, depois eu reparei que não conseguia aceder à entidade dentro do código para fazer alterações, ler, etc.